# LC3: Simulator shows outdated instruction despite loading updated file

Tags: assembly, lc3

**EDIT: Silly mistake... I was saving my project file but I wasn't assembling my new code. Whoops!**

In my simulator I have an instruction called `LEA R2, ZSTR`. This is a mistake I later fixed to `LEA R0, ZSTR` so that TRAP x22 could print the string in the proper register (R0 instead of R2). However in my code below under `ZERO CASE INSTRUCTIONS` you can see that I *do* in fact have `LEA R0, ZSTR`, so I don't know why it's still showing `LEA R2, ZSTR`. I've tried restarting the simulator to no avail thinking it's a bug. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

**CODE: Section removed**

Comment: Which LC-3 simulator are you using?  (or is there only one implementation that everyone uses)?   Do you have to rebuild your executable after source changes, or does that normally happen automatically every time you debug / run it?

Comment: I'm using one from McGraw-Hill. I'm not exactly sure if there's only one implementation though. I figured it out, by the way! It was a silly mistake. Basically I was saving but I hadn't clicked assemble... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah, so it was what I suggested in my earlier comment.  I've only read about LC-3, not tried it, so I didn't know if the simulator made that mistake possible or not.

Comment: No worries. I appreciate your help!